# How to access numeric constants using the Float trait?

Tags: generics, rust, constants

I want to write generic mathematical code in Rust. The types `f32` and `f64` already define constants. E.g. π is `std::f32::consts::PI`.

I understand that the `Float` trait provides common functions, but how about constants?

My attempt:

```
extern crate num;

use self::num::traits::Float;

fn f<T: Float>(t: T) -> T { 
    T::consts::PI * t 
}   

fn main() {
    let x = 5.0f32;
    println!("Result: {}", f(x));
}
```

yields:

```
main.rs:6:5: 6:18 error: associated type `consts` not found for `T` [E0220]
main.rs:6     T::consts::PI * t
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

If this is not possible, then how may I access mathematical constants using a generic type `T`?

Comment: Note that `std::f32` and `std::f64` are modules. They're not the same thing as the primitive types `f32` and `f64`. The modules are named like this to make it clear that they are related to the primitive types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a feature called *associated constants*. It doesn't appear that num 0.1.41 makes use of any such constants, but you could augment the `Float` trait like this:

```
extern crate num;

trait FloatConst: num::Float {
    const PI: Self;
    const E: Self;
}

impl FloatConst for f32 {
    const PI: f32 = 3.14;
    const E: f32 = 2.71;
}

impl FloatConst for f64 {
    const PI: f64 = 3.14159;
    const E: f64 = 2.71828;
}

fn f<T: FloatConst>(t: T) -> T {
    t + T::PI + T::E
}

fn main() {
    let x = 5.0f32;
    println!("Result: {}", f(x));
}
```

In previous versions of Rust, you will need to use functions:

```
extern crate num;

use num::traits::Float;

trait FloatConst {
    fn pi() -> Self;
}

impl FloatConst for f32 {
    fn pi() -> Self { std::f32::consts::PI }
}

impl FloatConst for f64 {
    fn pi() -> Self { std::f64::consts::PI }
}

fn f<T: Float + FloatConst>(t: T) -> T {
    T::pi() * t
}

fn main() {
    println!("Result: {}", f(5.0f32));
    println!("Result: {}", f(5.0f64));
}
```

I'd expect that monomorphization and compiler optimizations will make this about as fast it it could be, but profiling is always a good idea if needed.